# javascript: writing callable objects

Tags: javascript

Note: I simplified the logic greatly for this example. Please assume that I need the functions, closures etc. described.

Recently, I wrote a class:

```
function Foo () {
    var self = this;
    self.number = 0;
    self.methodA = methodA;

    /////

    function methodA () {
        self.number++;
    }
}
```

then, I decided I wanted to do the following:

```
function Bar() {
    Foo.call(this);

    this.methodA = methodA;

    var cleanFoo = new Foo();
    ////

    function methodA () {
        this.number = cleanFoo.methodA.call(this);
    }
}

Bar.prototype = Foo;
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
```

Basically, I would like `Bar` to inherit from `Foo`, to override `methodA` but call `Foo`'s `methodA` from the overridden one.

I realized though, that, in its current state, I couldn't call `Foo`'s `methodA` because it was referencing `self` which, when I call it from a clean object, would reference the clean object even though I passed in a different context.

I decided that the way to solve this is to rewrite the `Foo` like this:

```
function Foo () {            
        this.number = 0;
        this.methodA = methodA;

        /////

        function methodA () {
            var self = this; //assume I need this closure in methodA for logic that has been edited out.
            self.number++;
        }
}
```

However, then, I realized that I wanted to add `methodB` to `Foo` which calls `methodA`:

```
function Foo () {
    this.number = 0;
    this.methodA = methodA;

    /////

    function methodA () {
        var self = this; //assume I need this closure in methodA for logic that has been edited out.
        self.number++;
    }

    function methodB () {
            methodA();   
           return this.number;
        }
    }
```

but I realized that that when I did this that `self` in `methodA` would be `methodB`. I solved this by changing the call in `methodB` to `this.methodA()` which ensures that the context in `methodA` is the object itself and not methodB.

Am I correct? Is this the way to build a class so that its methods are callable? Am I missing something obvious.

Comment: I don't understand  setting `Bar.prototype = Foo;` and then changing`Foo`'s constructor from `Function` to `Bar`. Did you mean `Bar.prototype = Object.create (Foo.prototype);`  or perhaps even `Bar.prototype = new Foo()'?

Comment: Yes, I meant Bar.prototype = new Foo(), sorry made some mistakes when I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call a parent's method that is defined on the prototype from an overriden subclass method, you can access the prototype directly.

If `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo`, then you can call the `Foo` version of the method like this:

```
Bar.prototype.methodB = function () {
    // call base class implementation
    Foo.prototype.methodB.call(this);
}
```

If the method is not defined on the prototype but is set in the constructor, then you have to save the prior reference to the method before you override it in the derived constructor.

```
function Bar() {
     Foo.call(this);

     var oldMethodB = this.methodB;
     this.methodB = function() {
         // call base class implementation
         oldMethodB.call(this);
     }
}
```

You can use either [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to set the appropriate value of `this` when calling the base class method.

I'm not sure if this is a point of confusion for you or not, but keep in mind that there's only one `this` value for derived and base class instance.  Some people get confused thinking there's a different `this` for the `Bar` component of an object versus the `Foo` component of the object.  That is not the case.  It's one object with properties from each class on the same object.  So, when you want to call a `Foo` method with the appropriate `this` value, you can use the `this` value from an appropriately called `Bar` method.

---

In addition, this line is not correct:

```
Bar.prototype = Foo;
```

That should be:

```
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
```

Comment: I guess I was looking to confirm two things. When writing a class: 1) I cannot use 'var self = this' at the top of the constructor and then use self in all its methods because then the methods cannot be called and provided a context on which to operate. 2) When I call one method from another I should always call them using 'this.method()' so that the context is maintained. Are these two correct?

Comment: @pQuestions123 - item 1) seems partially wrong.  You can still call parent methods on the same object even though you're using `self` because `this` for the derived class is the same as `self` will be (they are the same object).  The part that is correct is that you cannot force a method into a context in which it does not belong when using a closure-based `self`.  But a derived object is the correct context.  item 2) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track!  jfriend00 did a great job explaining.  Here is my answer to this anyways.

You have a parent class `(Bar)` that is handling the core elements of your application.  Lets say you want to increase a number for a specific part of the application, you might make another class called `(Foo)`.

Heres how that might look:

```
var Bar = Class.create({
    initialize: function() {

      // initialize any variables      
      this.foo = new Foo();       
      // call foo 
      this.incrementFooNumber();

    },
    incrementFooNumber: function() {
      this.foo.incrementNumber();
    }
});

var Foo = Class.create({
        initialize: function() {
          // initialize any variables 
          var number = 0;
          // assign locally
          this.number = number;      

        },
        incrementNumber: function() {
          this.number++;
        }
    });
```

You can easily start `Bar` by calling: `var bar = new Bar();`  Now you can see that we initiate `Bar` and inside `Bar` is where we assign locally the `Foo` instance and than call `incrementFooNumber` which calls the method `incrementNumber` inside `Foo`.